# Why isnt multiple else if statements not working to create flot graph?

Tags: string, compare, flot, if-statement

```
if(options == verticlebar_graph ){
plot(plotname, plotdata, verticlebar_options);
}
else if(options == linechart_graph){
plot(plotname, plotdata, linechart_options);
}
else if(options == pie_graph){
plot(plotname, plotdata, pie_chart_options);
}
else{
plot(plotname, plotdata, options);
}
```

Comapring is done only in the first if statement, not parsing through th eother else if statements

Comment: Is it plotting anything?

Comment: Yes,it is plotting the first if statement, the problem is the else if statements are not parsed

Comment: That is why they aren't. As soon as one of the comparisons evaluates to true, the program performs whatever actions are inside that comparison's inner block, and then stops checking the rest of the else ifs. Using else if is basically saying "If this is true, do something, but if that first thing is false and this second thing is true, do something else, and so on." If you want to check all of the ifs, regardless of which ones are true, then take out all of the else's so it's just `if verticalbar`, `if linechart`, `if pie`.

Comment: Tried that too, actually i have 3 different graphs for which i'l pass 3 different options(types of graph check this 'http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-types/index.html') and each graph shd parse all the statements, which ever is true that particular graph should be plotted

Comment: It seems like you want to have the code you posted executed for each of the three graphs, correct? There are a few ways you can do that. If your graphs are in an array, you can surround your if else if in a loop. Or you could place it in a function that you can call with each of your graphs.

Comment: Yes ur right! but how can i add a for loop here? on what basis shal i calculate the for loop variable? the graphs are in different sections and they dont have anything in common :( .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only plotting the first graph because that is the only one that you are checking. Depending on how your graphs' information is stored, you can check all of them in a few different ways. But one important thing to always do with code that is reused is to put it in a function.

```
function plot_the_graph(plotname, plotdata, options) {

    if(options == verticlebar_graph ){
        plot(plotname, plotdata, verticlebar_options);
    }
    else if(options == linechart_graph){
        plot(plotname, plotdata, linechart_options);
    }
    else if(options == pie_graph){
        plot(plotname, plotdata, pie_chart_options);
    }
    else{
        plot(plotname, plotdata, options);
    }

}
```

Now you can use that function for all of your graphs. If you have the graphs stored in an array, then you can use a simple for loop to plot all of them. It might look something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_of_graphs.length; i++) {
    plot_the_graph(
            array_of_graphs[i].plotname,
            array_of_graphs[i].plotdata,
            array_of_graphs[i].options
        );
}
```

Or if they are all separate objects:

```
plot_the_graph(graph1_plotname, graph1_plotdata, graph1_options);
plot_the_graph(graph2_plotname, graph2_plotdata, graph2_options);
plot_the_graph(graph3_plotname, graph3_plotdata, graph3_options);
```

Note that these code examples are just guesses at how your data is stored in the code. It's very likely that you will have to change parts of it.

Comment: This is what i have done, problem is first graph will take the if statement if correct- plotted, else its taking the default, the 'ELS IF' part is not parsed by the code
(All 3 graphs are in same page)

Comment: It's most likely actually checking those ones, but just not evaluating them to true. Take out the `else`  in the `else if` parts, and if it's still not doing anything in the cases where you think the graph should be a linechart or a pie_chart, then there is either something seriously wrong with the javascript evaluator, or `linechart_graph` and `pie_graph` are the actual value of `options` in those cases.

Comment: linechart_graph and pie_graph are the values m passing to a function, if thee option is == to those names then dif graph is plotted, m not understanding y the second graph is not parsing the els if? any specific ans fr this?

Comment: I was actually just about to ask if they were strings or not haha. Because that does make a difference.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer though. Good luck on the rest of your application :)